# Nginx - redirect to few applications

Tags: nginx

I'a completly newbie in Nginx using.
I've got VPS with 3 applications running on various port:
FirstApp localhost:8080
SecondApp localhost:4000
ThirdApp localhost:8085.

FirstApp working good and Nginx redirect correctly, bu I want to redirect to other like that:
* domain-name.com/ 
* domain-name.com/secondApp
* domain-name.com/thirdApp

Now i can do that, but have to go to domain-name.com:4000

What should I do ?
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

         root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general principle: more location blocks!

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location /secondApp {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }

    location /thirdApp {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8085;
    }
```

This style of location is called "prefix match", so the middle block will match all paths that start with `/secondApp`. When selecting a match, nginx picks the longest match possible, so although `/secondApp/with/a/url` matches both `/` and `/secondApp`, nginx will pick the middle block because it has the longest match.